# Storing & Reading documents present in iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud

i want to develop an iPad app where i can store a list of PDF files/ iWork files in iCloud.

Finally any user who is using this app can able to download & read(only read no write) these documents inside my App.

Also i want to enable the autosync functionality in my app .So user can see updated document always.

Is this Possible ? What is the right way to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Have you google anything?

Comment: yes i have done it but i am confused with the result because iCloud has its own app like like Notes, iWork... So i am wondering as per my requirement this is feasible or not ?

Comment: or i have to look some other service providers like Dropbox ?

Comment: You might have got working iCloud sandbox URL. Make sure iCloud is enabled and functioning properly.

Comment: iCloud does not "have its own app". Any app can use iCloud. Please go and read a little bit of Apple's developer documentation about iCloud, and come back if you have more specific questions about using it.